# Compare two columns with different data types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns in a table with different data types, how can i compare these two columns to look for similar values.

```
Table
column_a(int)  column_b(nvarchar)
-------------  -----------------
1               Apple
2               Mango
3               5
4               2
5               Book
```

I tried below query but did not work. Kindly suggest.

```
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE
CAST(column_a AS nvarchar)
IN 
(SELECT column_b FROM tab)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us an example of similar value between the two columns ?

Comment: The real question is why are you storing what is supposed to be numerical data in a `varchar`? Alphanumerical and Numerical data types don't act the same. For example, `'10'` is **less than** `'2'`.

Comment: @xXx , example is in question

Comment: @Larnu , nvarchar column is for comments, thus it has got num values as well

Comment: @FaisalAlinn can you please share your expected output ?

Comment: @xXx , Thanks, i want to view row 2 and 5 to be printed as output

Comment: `'2'` isn't a comment; it's just a number.

Comment: @Larnu , i mean this column is for comments , 2 is a form of comment in my table

Comment: It appears that the OPs sample data is [not representative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59303470/compare-two-columns-with-different-data-types/59304378#comment104811507_59304378) of their real data; making the real problem impossible to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Use self join for this

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM TAB A
INNER JOIN TAB B ON CAST(A.column_a as nvarchar) = LTRIM(RTRIM(B.column_b))
```

Comment: Hey Akash, Query runs but Gives zero records.

Comment: That's weird, I tested on my own DB and it works, maybe you have whitespaces in `NVARCHAR` column, try trimming the values (see updated query in snippet above)

Comment: Unfortunately, Zero records even after trim

UPDATE tab SET [column] = LTRIM(RTRIM([column]))

Comment: it worked fine on a test table, but did not worked with my existing table, there might be an issue with my current table. Thanks

Comment: Oh, yeah, add more details when you find them and need help. [what to do when someone answers your queston](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `TRY_CONVERT` and an `EXISTS` to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ColumnA int,
                            ColumnB nvarchar(5));
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ColumnA,ColumnB)
VALUES (1,'Apple'),
       (2,'Mango'),
       (3,'5'),
       (4,'2'),
       (5,'Book');
GO

SELECT YT.ColumnA,
       YT.ColumnB
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.YourTable sq
              WHERE YT.ColumnA = TRY_CONVERT(int,sq.ColumnB));
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=50e2f5966ae887a33f20edcc6ce2665e)

This, however, **will** perform poorly in a large table as the query is not SARGable (due to the `TRY_CONVERT`). As I mentioned in the comments, if you need to store numerical data, use a numerical data type.

Comment: it worked fine on a test table, but did not worked with my existing table, there might be an issue with my current table.
Thanks

Comment: Then provide us with representative sample data, @FaisalAlinn . It's no good giving us sample data that doesn't replicate the problem and then telling us the SQL we provide "doesn't work", when it does for the sample(s) you've provided.

Comment: Thanks for your concern and support. I am afraid as the data is categorized as confidential by the company.

Comment: I didn't ask for *actual* data, @FaisalAlinn, I asked for **representative**. Not the same thing.